# jQuery Datatables - Sum Column with class in cell

Tags: jquery, class, sum, datatables, cell

I am trying to sum several columns in a datatables.net table (column 5, 6, 7) so that in the footer of each of these columns the sum of that column shows.

The issue is that in one cell there are multiple values and the other cells have the value wrapped in a span tag. Therefore the total is showing as NaN

Is there a way to use the footerCallback method by not only declaring the column but also declaring the class?

or what would be the best way to get the columns to sum (and show the current page sum and the sum across all pages - which is what happens with the footercallback method)

I have tried many different things including declaring variables, adding .cell ('.classname') and .cells (.'classname') but nothing returns the sum. It seams to work fine if there is nothing else in the cell except for the value but that isn't an option for my table.

Here is the datatables code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#example').dataTable({
    "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api(),
            data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api.column(6)
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        });

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api.column(6, {
            page: 'current'
        })
            .data()
            .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        }, 0);

        // Update footer
        $(api.column(6).footer()).html(
            '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)');
    }
});
```

});`

The table code is fairly complex so I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ittavi/9p7tkqsn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reduce methods had a problem.

variable b in your reduce method is not the number(money), instead it is the  tag that is used in the column which looks like

`$<span class=" addExpChangedClass amtField paymentparent1 sumamount" data-sort="1.00">1.00</span>`

Steps:

1. I first got rid of the `$` in the beginning by `b.replace('$', '')`
2. Then converted the rest of the string to a jQuery object so that the value (which is the amount) can be extracted `$(b.replace('$', '')).text();`.

Finally it looks like below

```
total = api.column(6)
  .data()
  .reduce(function(total, b) {
    b = $(b.replace('$', '')).text();
    return total + parseInt(b);
  }, 0);
// Total over this page
pageTotal = api.column(6, {
    page: 'current'
  })
  .data()
  .reduce(function(total, b) {
    b = $(b.replace('$', '')).text();
    return total + parseInt(b);
  }, 0);
```

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9p7tkqsn/5/)

Hope this helps.